using a canvas in gtkmm, now for gtkmm 4
More than 10 years ago I started an application with a canvas widget (goocanvas) in gtkmm3.
My last question about this topic was: using a canvas in gtkmm application
Now I have to learn that gtkmm3 is not longer maintained... furthermore, the canvas widget goocanvas itself is not maintained for years now. I tried today to build it without any success. The autogen.sh is such old that id did not do anything useful on my OS. As this, to continue my development I have to switch to something new.
But the question is the same as 12 years ago! I have no idea which canvas I can use. Seems to be that there is nothing left in gtk4!
Is there any idea how to can get a canvas into gtk anymore?
Currently the only idea I have is to go with swig and tcl/tk.  But that means a year of work for... nothing.

you might want to check up on GTK's Drawing widget
https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.DrawingArea.html
I have seen other entities like PLplot, use this to create their own canvas class to draw widgets like graph or something essentially.
You might be able to replace the canvas in your old code with GtkDrawingArea.
